# Chartist.js - data points not visible, issue with formatting json data

Tags: json, chartist.js

I am using [Chartist.js](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html) to generate a chart dynamically using json data derived from multiple text inputs. The chart itself is generated with the proper labels series but no data points show, just the x and y axis. I've discovered that chartist needs an additional set of brackets '[ ]' around the data for it too work.

My json data looks like this:

```
{labels: ['07:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00'],
 series: [333, 444, 322, 222]}
```

Chartist needs the series data to be written like this: `series: [[333, 444, 322, 222]]`

I am initiating Chartist like this:

```
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data);
```

I need a bit of help in getting the extra brackets around the generated series data. I have searched for a method but all I can find are examples where the data is already set, not generated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the series from your data, and assign them in their respective places.

```
 var dataJson = {labels: ['07:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00'],
 series: [333, 444, 322, 222]} 

new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
labels: dataJson.labels,
series: [dataJson.series]
}, {
   fullWidth: true,
   chartPadding: {
   right: 40
  }
});
```

Let me know if it worked.